# How do I set tile width during initialize in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I need to calculate the prefTileWidth of a TilePane based on the width of the window. I wrote a method for this and when I print to the console it shows the correct widths, but they're not applied in the TilePane.

I found out that the width of the primaryStage is set after primaryStage.show() in Main. If I try to get primaryStage.getWidth before show() it returns NaN. However the TilePane is created before show(). So I need some way to get the width of the primaryStage at the time of creation of the TilePane. I've searched for a solution, but haven't found any. Does anyone know how to solve this?
This is a minimum working example of my code:

Controller:

```
public class Controller {
private static LinkedHashMap<String, BigDecimal> mProductMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
private double prefTileWidth;

@FXML private TilePane fieldContainer = new TilePane();

@FXML
public void initialize() {
    // I tried setting the prefTileWidth here,
    // but at this point I can't get the primaryStage.getWidth() yet, because that will return NaN
    try {
        importFrom(new File("mainMap.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    addButtons();
}

// calculates the prefTileWidth of the TilePane
public void tilePaneSize(double width) {
    fieldContainer.setPrefTileWidth(width / 2 - 10);
    prefTileWidth = fieldContainer.getPrefTileWidth();
    System.out.println("Width of primaryStage = " + width);   // returns 314.3999938964844
    System.out.println("tile width = " + prefTileWidth);   // returns 147.1999969482422
    // Outcomes are correct, but the tiles don't resize to prefTileWidth
    // How do I make this work?
}

// adds products and their prices to the LinkedHashMap mProductMap
public void addProduct(String product, BigDecimal price) {
    mProductMap.put(product, price);
}

// adds buttons to the TilePane
private void addButtons() {
    // clears the TilePane to prevent duplicate buttons
    fieldContainer.getChildren().clear();

    for (Map.Entry<String, BigDecimal> entry : mProductMap.entrySet()) {
        StackPane newField = new StackPane();
        Button main = new Button();
        Button multiply = new Button();
        Button subtract = new Button();

        main.setText(entry.getKey() + "\n" + entry.getValue());
        main.getStyleClass().add("main-btn-bg-color");
        multiply.getStyleClass().add("inner-button");
        multiply.getStyleClass().add("multiply-btn");
        subtract.getStyleClass().add("inner-button");
        subtract.getStyleClass().add("subtract-btn");
        StackPane.setAlignment(multiply, Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
        StackPane.setAlignment(subtract, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        StackPane.setMargin(multiply, new Insets(0, 0, 8, 8));
        StackPane.setMargin(subtract, new Insets(0, 0, 8, 16));

        newField.getChildren().add(main);
        newField.getChildren().add(multiply);
        newField.getChildren().add(subtract);
        fieldContainer.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        fieldContainer.getChildren().add(newField);
    }
}

// imports the map with products and prices from txt file
public void importFrom(File file) {
    try (
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    ) {
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] args = line.split("\\|");
            addProduct(new String(args[0]), new BigDecimal(args[1]));
        }
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.printf("Problems loading %s %n", file);
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/counter.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 500));
    // This is one solution I tried. Again it gets the right outcome, but the tiles are not responding to it:
    // Controller ctrl = new Controller();
    // ctrl.tilePaneSize(primaryStage.getScene().getWidth());
    primaryStage.show();

    Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    primaryStage.setMaxWidth(815);
    primaryStage.setMaxHeight(800);
    Controller ctrl = new Controller();
    ctrl.tilePaneSize(primaryStage.getWidth());

    if (visualBounds.getWidth() <= 800) {
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

FXML:

```
<BorderPane stylesheets="/css/main.css"
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:id="container"
        fx:controller="sample.controllers.Controller">

<center>
    <ScrollPane fx:id="scroll" hbarPolicy="NEVER" fitToWidth="true">
        <TilePane id="fieldContainer" fx:id="fieldContainer" prefTileHeight="100.0" vgap="5" hgap="5"> <!-- prefTileWidth="144.0" does work, but I don't want it to be hard coded here-->
        </TilePane>
    </ScrollPane>
</center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Note: In general it's a bad idea to initialize fields that are supposed to be injected by the `FXMLLoader`. You should probably remove the assignment here: `@FXML private TilePane fieldContainer = new TilePane();` I realized you probably did this to avoid a NPE when calling the `tilePaneSize` method from the start method, however the controller you create in the start method is not the same one used with the scene root.

Comment: Yeah, if I just write @FXML private TilePane fieldContainer, I get a NPE. I just tried setting the tilePaneSize method to static, so I can just call Controller.tilePaneSize() from Main without creating a new Controller. For this to work I also needed to set fieldContainer and prefTileWidth to static, but now, the buttons won't appear, so I can't see if this is going to work at all :(

Comment: `FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/counter.fxml")); Parent root = loader.load(); Controller ctrl = loader.getController();` Depending on your needs you may want to take a look at [`GridPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) though, since this allows you to specify the width relative to the width of the `GridPane`, see [`ColumnConstraints.percentWidth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/ColumnConstraints.html#percentWidthProperty).

Comment: That solved it. I will definitely have a look at GridPane.